# IO size vs block size?

Tags: performance, io, storage, latency, throughput

I have always been confused whether IO size is the same as block size. People have used it interchangeably when talking about storage performance. Can someone help me define the differences?

Answer (score 2):

They are not the same thing but they should be aligned for optimal performance. I/O size is the page size your application uses, for example 16KB for InnoDB, 8KB for PostgreSQL, etc.

Block size is configured at your storage level and can refer to several things. For example, it can refer to the block size used by your RAID array, which is the amount of data put on each disk in a stripe before moving to the next disk. It can refer to the block size of your file system (not adjustable on most file systems).

Comment: The way I understood it was that block size is how much information you take at at time. However, I'm still confused what IO size would be. I often see this relationship and am confused on how to interpret it: throughput = iops * IO size

Comment: That equation only applies to spinning rust where sequential access is fast but random access is slow. You can only reposition the heads about 120 times per second on a 7200 rpm disk, so you have at most 120 IOPS. So if each I/O is 1MB that is 120MB/s. If each I/O is 1KB, that is 120KB/s. This doesn't apply the same way to SSDs.